# Storyboard File Inspector

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

I submitted my app yesterday and i want this to run on iOS 6.0 and later operating systems.I have set the Deployment Target to 6.0 and Base SDK to Latest iOS(iOS 7.1).Is it ok?

Furthermore i would like to know which is the right selection for storyboard file in File Inspector Tab and in Interface Builder Document Section.Here is a screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

I have chosen Project Deployment Target(6.0) for Builds For option.Is there any problem with this?Where does this option refers to?Cause there is an option iOS 6.0 and later also to choose.So which of these two options i have to choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have set the Deployment Target to 6.0 and Base SDK to Latest iOS(iOS
>   7.1).Is it ok?
>   ***YES***
>
> I have chosen Project Deployment Target(6.0) for Builds For option.Is
>   there any problem with this?
>   ***NO, Its just a minimum target***.

Comment: Thanks Kumar for your answer.Can you explain me a little more about Builds For Option for Storyboard? Why does "iOS 6.0 and later" option exists too?

Comment: If you have chosen as the latest SDK for base, then that too included from the **Build For**

Comment: And also check your architecture in the Build settings.

Comment: Architectures have been set to: Standard Architectures(armv7,armv7s,arm64) .Is this right?